# Declare Layout_Params.flag_secure in menifest

Tags: android, screenshot, video-capture, capture, android-screen

Android application screen can be prevent from taking screenshot via this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

But it is messy to write this code in every screen. Have any way to declare it in manifest application or any where.

Comment: AFAIK the only attribute available is `android:windowSoftInputMode` which will set SoftInput flag . So you need to set WindowManager's Flags at runtime .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `BaseActivity` for your app and make all the other Activities extend it.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   }
}
```

Then you create your activities like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // Your code
       }
}
```

Comment: your answer solved my problem though it does not fulfill the question's requirements.

Comment: Also see my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215